# Как в FluentAssertions сравнить два разных класса с совпадениями по полям?

Tags: c#, классы, юнит-тесты, сравнение, fluent-assertions

Допустим есть два не всязанных наследованием класса. У них есть несколько совподающих полей (в примере ниже это поля field_1 и field_2)

```
class A
{
    int field_1;
    int field_2;

    int field_3;
}

class B
{
    int field_1;
    int field_2;

    int field_4;
} 

A a = new A {field_1 = 1, field_2 = 2, field_3 = 3}
B b = new B {field_1 = 1, field_2 = 2, field_4 = 4}
```

Можно ли написать нечто подобное `a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b);` и получить положительный результат?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перегрузить метод `Equals`. В паре с ним всегда следует перегружать метод `GetHashCode`. Они были любезно [сгенерированы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019) Студией автоматически, после чего я подправил метод `Equals`, чтобы происходило сравнение не только с объектом своего типа, но и другого.

```
public class A
{
    public int field_1;
    public int field_2;

    public int field_3;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is A a)
        {
            return field_1 == a.field_1
                && field_2 == a.field_2
                && field_3 == a.field_3;
        }
        else if (obj is B b)
        {
            return field_1 == b.field_1
                && field_2 == b.field_2;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = -1805700735;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field_1.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field_2.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int field_1;
    public int field_2;

    public int field_4;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is B b)
        {
            return field_1 == b.field_1
                && field_2 == b.field_2
                && field_4 == b.field_4;
        }
        else if (obj is A a)
        {
            return field_1 == a.field_1
                && field_2 == a.field_2;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = -1805700735;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field_1.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field_2.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Этот способ полезен не только для модульного тестирования, но и для сравнения объектов в реальном коде.

---

Если сравниваемые типы нельзя/нежелательно менять, то можно обойтись возможностями FluentAsserions:

```
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b, options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers());
```

По умолчанию `BeEquivalentTo` сравнивает все члены объектов. Но можно исключить из сравнения отсутствующие.

Или, наоборот, можно указать только те свойства/поля, которые должны участвовать в сравнении:

```
a.Should().BeEquivalentTo(b, options => options
    .Including(x => x.field_1).Including(x => x.field_2));
```

Документация: [Object graph comparison](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/)

Comment: может быть вы сможете подсказать, как провернуть аналогичное сравнение по отдельным полям но уже с коллекциями?

Comment: @ЛАНТАН - дайте больше информации, что за коллекции. И лучше задать отдельный вопрос (создайте новую тему)